# Pseudo Tcp channel

Tags: tcp, channel

What is a pseudo-tcp channel and how can it be implemented?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pseudo-TCP is a protocol that implements some of the ideas of TCP to provide a reliable data stream over an unreliable, packet-based interface.  This could be used, for example, if you had access to only UDP but wanted a reliable way to pass data.

You can find example code here:
[Google Code - PseudoTCP Channel (Header File)](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/branches/nextsnap/talk/session/tunnel/pseudotcpchannel.h)
[Google Code - PseudoTCP Channel (CC File)](http://code.google.com/p/libjingle/source/browse/branches/nextsnap/talk/session/tunnel/pseudotcpchannel.cc)